# How do I use a monoid instance of a function?

Tags: haskell, monoids

Today I tried to reduce a list of functions trough monoid typeclass but the resulting function expects its argument to be an instance of Monoid for some reason.

GHCI tells me that the type of `mconcat [id, id, id, id]` is `Monoid a => a -> a`. Yet I would expect it to be `a -> a`.

What is happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using this instance:

```
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) where
    mempty _ = mempty
    mappend f g x = f x `mappend` g x
```

which is more general because it doesn't require endomorphisms (i.e. `a -> a`). To get the instance you were expecting, you can wrap your functions in `Endo`:

```
appEndo (mconcat [Endo id, Endo id, Endo id, Endo id])
```

or

```
appEndo $ mconcat $ fmap Endo [id, id, id, id]
```

Comment: Yet another alternative: `appEndo $ foldMap Endo [id,id,id,id]`

Comment: So, `Monoid Endo` has `mempty = id ; mappend = (.)`, if I understand correctly?